# How to use CausesValidation on an ext.net button?

Tags: ext.net

This question is about `ext.net`.

I hope to perform a form validation when the save button is clicked. In a regular ASP.NET webform, we usually use `CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="gpSubmit"` on the save button. But in an ext.net button, those two properties seems to be ineffective.

Any advice? How do you focus on the DOM control that fails the validation?

Here is my code.

```
<ext:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Icon="ApplicationEdit" 
    CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="gpSubmit">
    <DirectEvents>
        <Click 
            OnEvent="btnSave_Click" 
            Before="...;"
            Success="...;"
            Failure="...;">
            <EventMask ShowMask="true" Msg="Processing" />
            </Click>
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

Comment: Do you need remote or local validation? Can you use only Ext.NET validation or you have to use ASP.NET validation?

Comment: Either way will be fine, as long as the failed DOM control can get the focus after the validation.

Comment: Take  a look at this one [form validation before direct click event fire][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001045/form-validation-before-direct-click-event-fire